# DNA Test: Probability question -- matter of interpretation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

> A crime has been committed in a town of 100,000 inhabitants. The police are looking for a single perpetrator, believed to live in the town. DNA evidence is found on the crime science. Kevin's DNA matches the DNA recovered from the crime scene. According to DNA experts, the probability that a random person's DNA matches the crime scene DNA is 1 in 10,000. **Before** the DNA evidence, Kevin was **no more likely to be** the guilty person than any other person in town. What is the probability that Kevin is guilty after the DNA evidence appeared?

My answer:

Kevin is no more likely to be the perpetrator than any one else in the town. I AM assuming that they checked the DNA evidence against every town inhabitant (otherwise, they thought Kevin was more likely than any other town inhabitant to be the perpetrator and only tested it against his, and maybe against that of a few others). So, assuming 1 in 10,000 have the 100,000 came back positive, Kevin is one among ten inhabitants whose DNA matched with that found on the crime scene. Therefore, there is a $\frac{1}{10}$ probability that Kevin is the criminal.

---

Solution given:

[image]

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: If we tested everyone, we expect about 10 false positives (more precisely $\frac {99,999}{10,000}$) and one true positive for 11 total positive results.  Of which, Kevin is one.

Comment: Thanks Shaun and Doug!

Comment: Except, it doesn't say anything about false positives. It just says a random test will have a chance of 1/10000.

Comment: " Kevin is no more likely to be the perpetrator than any one else in the town" and " Therefore, there is a 1/10 probability that Kevin is the criminal".  You realize those are utterly contradictory statements, don't you?

Comment: I meant before anyone is tested.

Comment: I do realize that the way it would seem to you, it would seem contradictory.

Comment: But thanks for you input flea hood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some ambiguity about whether the "1 in 10,000" fraction refers to any random person or to any random *innocent* person. The given solution is assuming the latter (notice it says $P(A\mid  G^c)=\frac1{10000}$). If you also assume the latter, then your argument will agree with the solution: the guilty person will test positive, and so will $\frac1{10,000}$ of the remaining 99,999 townsfolk, meaning 10.9999 people in total will come back positive. Kevin is one person in that total.

Comment: Well the question said "random person" so is that assumption in the solution wrong? Also, what would $P(A|G^c)$ be if the former was assumed?

Comment: Would $P(A|G^c)=\frac{9}{100000}$?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a better grasp on this problem is to think of the four possibilities:

1. Kevin is guilty and the DNA test is not a match
2. Kevin is guilty and the DNA test is a match
3. Kevin is not guilty and the DNA test is not a match
4. Kevin is not guilty and the DNA test is a match.

Once the DNA test comes back as a match, we're restricting ourselves to situations 2 and 4, which leads to the calculation as given by the textbook.

Even if the police test everyone, you would still expect about 10 people from the 99999 who aren't Kevin to show up as positive, leading Kevin to be one of (about) 11 people who test positive.

Comment: Why can't it be interpreted that Kevin in simply one of those 10 people of the 100000 that come back positive?

Comment: All we are told is that Kevin came back positive. But he was randomly tested. And so would everyone else have been. Meaning that 10 people came back positive.

Comment: No, this is not true. All we know is that Kevin was tested: we don't know that anyone else was tested. And even if everyone else was tested, we would still expect to find about 10 (really, 99999/10000) people who also tested positive from the people who aren't Kevin.

Comment: Ok. I think this shed's light on my confusion. Why was Kevin tested as if he were not equally likely among all inhabitants to be the criminal? From the account, is it not fair to assume that if Kevin is tested, EVERYONE is tested?

Comment: Don't forget the killer will test positive as well.  So there will be 9.9999 innocent peple who test positive and 1 person who tested positive. That's 11 total.

Comment: You're putting things out of order. You're assuming everyone was tested, and then Kevin was identified as one of the people who tested positive. This is not what the problem says: it only says that Kevin was tested and returned positive. It is important to only assume what's given in the problem: your extra assumptions about what would have been "fair to assume" are the source of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Thing is: Kevin is guilty and positive will happen 1 in 100,000 times. That Kevin is innocent and positive will happen 9.9999 in 100,000 times, and that Kevin is innocent and negative will occur 99,989.0001 out of 100,000 times. So Kevin testing positive will occur 10.9999 $\aprox $ 11 times. And for one of those times Kevin is guilty.